# Minecraft Server closes immediately after running?

Tags: server, minecraft, hamachi

Sorry if it's not the right place to ask this, I'm a bit new here.

Everything was **PERFECT**. I did a *Hamachi* server with a friend. My friend put his ***IPv4 in "server-ip="*** in the server properties. We needed only to open the Server file and the Hamachi software(we are sharing a network). One day I had a bad Internet signal (it s not related to the problem) and from that moment (just like two days ago) it happens this:

1. My friend opens the hamachi software.
2. He opens the server file in the folder.
3. The server is closed immediately without doing nothing.

I have done some tries with the server properties and realized that in some way the server-ip= is not correct. Because if I delete what s written in that line it doesn't close immediately(but we can t play that way).

I really don t know what to do and we would want to continue playing.

***Thanks if you read and if you can help!***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to leave `server-ip` blank. I know that for sure.
Here are some things you can try.

Double check the server's ip is correct.

Double check that you are trying to connect to the right port.

Make sure EULA is set to true in eula.txt

That's all I can tell you based off the vague information provided in your question. Please provide stuff like what error messages you were getting, what you mean by "We share a network", etc. I would like to help you but you probably need to talk to Hamachi's tech support.

Comment: @Pichi *was this actually the solution*?

Answer (score 0):

Most Likely your IP changed. Go execute the ipconfig command in CMD and check if it changed

Comment: please can you expand on your answer to give examples of how to check the change, and how to go about fixing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. The server closed immediatly after starting it. I tried to remove the ip from server-ip=, and the server didn't close, just like in your case. Then i reentert the exact same ip and suddenly it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score -1):

when that happens I remove and reinter the IP in the server and the pc.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer on how to write helpful answers